# What are the MatchNumericCriterion in QBPOSSDK Query Request

Tags: qbxml

I am attempting to query open purchase orders.   My first attempt was to use the PurchaseOrderStatusDesc="Open" however the return was Unsupported filter (PurchaseOrderStatusDesc).  I would then like to try UnfilledPercentageFilter however here is no documentation regarding this filter and particular the enums for MatchNumericCriterion.

Answer (score 0):

Request should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbposxml version="1.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
  <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <PurchaseOrderQueryRq requestID = "21">
    <PurchaseOrderStatusDesc >Open</PurchaseOrderStatusDesc>
    </PurchaseOrderQueryRq>
  </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBPOSXML>
```

Comment: Mine looks the same except there is an additional node. <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbposxml version="1.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
  <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <PurchaseOrderQueryRq requestID = "21">
    <TxnID>7412389040912</TxnID>
    <PurchaseOrderStatusDesc >Open</PurchaseOrderStatusDesc>
    </PurchaseOrderQueryRq>
  </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBPOSXML>

I get the error Unsupported filter (PurchaseOrderStatusDesc)

I am using QBPOS V8